# Static methods vs repository pattern with Linq2Sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, static-methods

I've hit on the idea of creating static methods on the partial Linq queries such as

```
public partial class User
{
    public static User FindByGuid(string guid, ApplicationDataContext context)
    {
        return context.Users.Where(x => x.GUID == guid).Single();
    }
}
```

So, for example, I can easily find a user by doing:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDataContext())
{
    var user = DataAccess.User.FindByGuid(UsersDropDown.SelectedValue, context);
}
```

Is this a recognised design pattern? What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing this vs the repository model?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't see a recognized pattern in what your doing here I do see that you are using Dependency Injection by passing the applicationdatacontext into the method as a dependency.  The problem here is that you are still tightly coupled to your datacontext regardless of where the dependency is initiated which makes it more difficult to unit test.